# Android Room: Type converter for String Date to Long?

Tags: android, android-room

I store my dates in my database as strings. This worked fine when using MySQL, however using room in android I cannot search by date to and date from in my queries correctly as room doesn't recognise the string dates. I'm wondering is it possible to use the type converter to simply convert the string into the long. Rather than having to redo my whole database to store Date instead of string then convert from Date to long.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
/**
 * Method used to gain the current date.
 *
 * @return
 */
private Date currentDate() {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
    return calendar.getTime();
}

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
String dateTimeOfWorkout = dateFormat.format(currentDate());
```

I got this:

```
  @TypeConverter
  public static Date fromTimestamp(String value) {
  if (value != null) {
    try {
        return df.parse(value);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
} else {
    return null;
}
```

QUERY

```
 // Get Monthly Logs
 @Query("SELECT checkInTable.checkInId, checkInTable.moodBeforeId, " +
    "checkInTable.checkInEntry, checkInTable.checkInEntry2, " +
    "checkInTable.userId, moodBeforeTable.workoutDate,   
     moodBeforeTable.moodBefore, " +
    "moodBeforeTable.moodBeforePK " +
    "FROM checkInTable " +
    "JOIN moodBeforeTable " +
    "ON checkInTable.moodBeforePK = moodBeforeTable.moodBeforePK " +
    "WHERE moodBeforetable.workoutDate >= datetime('now', '-1 month') " +
    "ORDER BY moodBeforeTable.workoutDate DESC")
     LiveData<List<CheckInLogsPojo>> getCheckInLogsMonthly();
```

MODEL

```
 @NonNull
 @ColumnInfo(name = "workoutDate")
 @TypeConverters({TimeTypeConverter.class})
 private String workoutDate;
```

UPDATE: With the above typer converter and query it is still not sorting results for a 1 month period. Its just showing everything.

Comment: This might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53668302/android-room-change-type-of-column-with-migration

Comment: Can you post an example format of your string?

Comment: can you shown exactly how is ur date formated? A sample.

Comment: added the format of the string to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without redo the whole database. It can be done using  Database migration.

Using type convertor date can be stored in database.

Add a class for converting date to long

```
public class DateConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    public static Date toDate(Long timestamp){
        return timestamp == null ? null : new Date(timestamp);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Long toTimestamp(Date date){
        return date == null ? null : date.getTime();
    }
}
```

Now we tell to the Room to use the DateConvertor we added using TypeConverts anotation

```
@Database(entities = {MyEntity.class},version = 1,exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
public abstract class MyDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    //room database
}
```

Now we can use Date as a data type in entity class

Comment: Im aware of that from reading the documentation. My question was "is it possible to use the type converter to simply convert the string into the long. Rather than having to redo my whole database to store Date instead of string then convert from Date to long."

Comment: It can be done using Database migration without doing whole database again.