# Date Converter in Room Android

Tags: android, android-room

I get date in this format from the server "2021-04-25T14:05:03". I wrote date type in my model and I want to add database date type.
this is my model

```
@Entity(tableName = "order_table")
data class Order(
    val adress: String? = null,
    val clientName: String? = null,
    val clientUnicId: String? = null,
    val mobileNumber: String? = null,
    val note: String? = null,
    val orderDate: Date? = null,
    @PrimaryKey
    val orderId: Int,
    var status: Boolean? = null,
    val userId: Int? = null
)
```

In the examples I looked at, I couldn't see any converter example that would convert the date type. How should I write a converter to make my date type look like this in the database "2021-04-25 14:05:03"?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should not save date type into the database. Although, it is supported.

When you get the date data from server side. You should receive it as a String. And in the case, you want to save it into local database, you also should save it as a String.

Why? Because it is easy to convert a String to many other type of format to display.
For formatting the date, you can use SimpleFormatDate.

Document;
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat

How to use? Example

[Android SimpleDateFormat, how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277747/android-simpledateformat-how-to-use-it)

Comment: Totally agree with you, it is recommended to store the date as an epoch, you can convert it into desired date format.

Comment: Yes it is better to save date as an epoch.. then there are a differents solutions to get date as String. You can use kotlin extention or you can use Converter like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62063052/android-room-type-converter-for-string-date-to-long

Answer (score 0):

Storing dates in formats that are recognised by SQLite (see [Date and Time Functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)) can be quite beneficial.

1. They are directly sortable
2. They can be manipulated within queries (see example)
3. They can take up less storage and be more efficient

***YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss*** is such a format, although storage wise storing them as an integer (Long), which is recognised format can be marginally more efficient.

The **T** is an accepted separator (as per [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)) between the date and time, there is no need to change it to a space (it would not hurt to change it to a space).

**Example**

Here's an example that stores the date in YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss, and automatically converts the extracted date in the **Order** to a Date object.

After adding 3 rows, it extracts them, it then runs an update to add 7 days to all orders and extracts the modified data.

A version of the Order Entity (columns omitted for brevity) :-

```
@Entity
class Order {
    @PrimaryKey
    var orderId: Long? = 0L
    var date: String? = ""
    @Ignore
    var dateAsDate: Date? = null /* @Ignore so this is not a column in the table */

    /* Constructor that converts the date to a Date */
    constructor(orderId: Long?, date: String) {
        this.orderId = orderId
        this.date = date
        this.dateAsDate = SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_IN_DATABASE).parse(date)
    }
    companion object {
        const val DATE_FORMAT_IN_DATABASE = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
        const val SQLITE_STRFTIME_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
    }
}
```

**Dao** :-

```
@Dao
interface Dao {
    @Insert
    fun insert(order: Order): Long
    @Query("SELECT * FROM `order`")
    fun getAllOrders(): List<Order>
    @Query("UPDATE `order` SET date = strftime('${Order.SQLITE_STRFTIME_FORMAT}',date,'+7 days')")
    fun addAWeekToAllOrderDates()
    @Query("DELETE FROM `order`")
    fun deleteAllOrders()
}
```

- see Link above regarding the SQLite `strftime` function

The @Database is nothing special so omitted for brevity

An activity putting it all together that:-

1. gets an instance of the database
2. gets the Dao from the database
3. deletes any existing rows
4. adds 3 rows
5. extracts the 3 rows and prints the extracted date as per the database and the date as per the Date's `toString` method.
6. updates all the rows by adding 7 days using SQLite's `strftime` function.
7. extracts the 3 updated rows and prints the extracted date as per the database and the date as per the Date's `toString` method

:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: Dao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)!!
        dao = db.getDao()
        dao.deleteAllOrders()

        dao.insert(Order(null,"2021-01-01T12:15:00"))
        dao.insert(Order(null,"2021-02-01T12:15:00"))
        dao.insert(Order(null,"2021-03-01T12:15:00"))
        for(o: Order in dao.getAllOrders()) {
            Log.d("ORDERINFO","Extracted date is ${o.date} from Date is ${o.dateAsDate.toString()}")
        }
        dao.addAWeekToAllOrderDates()
        for(o: Order in dao.getAllOrders()) {
            Log.d("ORDERINFO","Extracted date is ${o.date} from Date is ${o.dateAsDate.toString()}")
        }
    }
}
```

**Result** (as output to the log) :-

```
2021-06-15 19:47:30.065 D/ORDERINFO: Extracted date is 2021-01-01T12:15:00 from Date is Fri Jan 01 12:15:00 GMT+11:00 2021
2021-06-15 19:47:30.066 D/ORDERINFO: Extracted date is 2021-02-01T12:15:00 from Date is Mon Feb 01 12:15:00 GMT+11:00 2021
2021-06-15 19:47:30.066 D/ORDERINFO: Extracted date is 2021-03-01T12:15:00 from Date is Mon Mar 01 12:15:00 GMT+11:00 2021


2021-06-15 19:47:30.073 D/ORDERINFO: Extracted date is 2021-01-08T12:15:00 from Date is Fri Jan 08 12:15:00 GMT+11:00 2021
2021-06-15 19:47:30.074 D/ORDERINFO: Extracted date is 2021-02-08T12:15:00 from Date is Mon Feb 08 12:15:00 GMT+11:00 2021
2021-06-15 19:47:30.074 D/ORDERINFO: Extracted date is 2021-03-08T12:15:00 from Date is Mon Mar 08 12:15:00 GMT+11:00 2021
```